# Getting the content of an iframe as a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have **aa.html**:

```
<html>
<body>
<span>555</span>
<iframe src="bb.html" id="fra"></iframe>
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById('fra');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(innerDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And **bb.html**:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>hi</p>
<script>
    document.write('<b>abc</b>');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I refresh **aa.html**, this is alerted:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I suppose this is **bb.html** but why isn't there `<p>hi</p>` and `<b>abc</b>`?

Comment: If you call console.log instead of alert what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Because iframes (like basically all external resources) load asynchronously. You can attach an `onload` event to the iframe and do your work there, and you'll see the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks. I guess jQuery on document ready function will also make this work?